# Сивка-бурка: что это значит

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, литература

Интересно было бы разобрать знаменитое заклинание из сказки: "Сивка-бурка, вещая каурка, встань передо мной, как лист перед травой!"
Во-первых, что это за масть такая, которая одновременно и сивая (серая), и бурая, и каурая? Почему вещая — более-менее понятно, конь все-таки волшебный. Но почему "как лист перед травой"?

Comment: В сказке - "*вещий*" каурка, а НЕ "*вещая*" каурка. Кто-то неправильно пересказал - и поехало...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Сивый* - "темно-серый с сединой". *Бурый* - "темно-коричневый с сероватым или красноватым оттенком" (ср.: бурёнка). *Каурый* - «дикая» масть; "светло-гнедой" (от сев.-тюрк. kovur "карий"), окраска туловища рыжеватая, грива и хвост рыже-коричневые, темнее корпуса. Кроме того, *кауриться, коуриться*  - быть угрюмым, показывать неудовольствие; глядеть исподлобья; упрямиться.

А знаете, говорят, трехцветная кошка - к счастью. Так, видимо, и конь, к тому же волшебный: соединение трех мастей подчёркивает сказочность персонажа. Все же сказочный конь не сивый, а разноцветный – седой, рыжий и бурый одновременно. Здесь символи­ка цвета очень понятна: седой, сивый – символ потустороннего мира смерти, Нави; рыжий, красный – символ кра­соты, цвет солнца – эмблема небесной Прави; бурый – цвет земли, обозначение Яви. У него «одна шерстинка» - золотая, как Солнце и звезды, другая – серебряная, как «Солнце мертвых» – Месяц. Во время Нави – ночью, он не столько ест пшеницу, сколько топчет ее – убивает.

Еще есть сведения, что три масти лошади означают три касты: жреческую (сивка), воинскую (бурка), земледельческую (каурка). (http://otvet.mail.ru/question/21749579/).

Вещий – тот, кому все ведомо и кто предвещает будущее; прорицатель, а также умно и говорящий. То есть, сивка-бурка вещая каур­ка – трехцветный конь-колдун.

Что касается приказания "Встань передо мной, как лист перед травой", то здесь нужно обратиться к знатокам фольклора. Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка объясняет, что "как лист перед травой" - устар., экспрес.; тотчас же, сразу, очень быстро (появиться перед кем-либо).